# linux bash file can not understand $((09))

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a bash script in that i had a Value=09
and when I used $((Value)) an error occurred:

09: value too great for base (error token is "09")

then I made a new bash file just with this line:

```
$((09))
```

and this had error again. I changed my way for that program but this question remained for me: Why? Whats wrong? Just 08 and 09 have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the base in bash. To force base 10:

```
Value=09
echo $((10#$Value * 2))  # ==> 18
```

From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers. A leading ‘0x’ or ‘0X’ denotes hexadecimal. Otherwise, numbers take the form [base#]n, where base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base. If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used.

Answer (score 5):

`09` is interpreted as [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). Use `9` if you want a decimal number.

Comment: Yes, Thank you, you were rigth. I teseted $((019)) and it was wrong too. what a bad way to make octal numbers...!

Answer (score 2):

The leading zero means: interpret the rest of the number in *octal* (base 8). This only allows for digits 0-7, so 9 is invalid.

There's also `0x` for *hexadecimal* (base 16), so `echo $((0xFF))` prints 255.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the programming languages, number starting with `0` is treated as [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).